# How to append raw data to boost::shared_array<char>?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I had:

```
message->data = boost::shared_array<char>(new char[100]);
```

And it was filled with data.

I received new `char * data` (from old C API) of `int length`. I want to expand my array with new data meaning write a copy of that new `data` after the end of my `message->data`.

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

Why not `shared_ptr<vector<char> >`?